# Literature in Esperanto and English

Tags: literature

I have found many fully translated pieces of Esperanto literature, but I am still a beginner, so these are difficult for me to understand. Therefore I am now looking for texts comprised of both English and Esperanto. Preferably one translation on either side. Do such texts exist, if so, where do I find them?

Answer (score 4):

Vi povas ŝerci ĉe [Vikifontaro](https://eo.wikisource.org/wiki/Enhavtabelo) aŭ [Gutenbergo-projekto](https://www.gutenberg.org/browse/languages/eo) tekstojn esperantigitajn de la angla, elŝuti la Ean kaj anglan versiojn, kaj malfermi ambaŭ samtempe sur via ekrano. Ekzemple: La falo de Ûsero-domo de Poe [en Eo](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/17425), [en la angla](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/932).

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice side-by-side English and Esperanto version of Alice in Wonderland [here](http://bilinguis.com/book/alice/eo/en/).

Answer (score 2):

The universal esperanto association has a website with easy texts: https://uea.facila.org/ 
And https://lernu.net has a big library with beginner friendly stories.

Answer (score 1):

Check the libroservo, the book selling service, at any Esperanto event. I'm sure the libroservisto will be delighted to help! I bought my copy of The Day We Became Cyborg / La Tago de Kiborgiĝo at the JES. It is a bilingual book with the side-by-side English and Esperanto versions you are looking for.

It can also be found in an online shop here: http://espero.sk/index.php?akcia=zmenjazyk&jazyk=EO

Answer (score 0):

*Traduku*, de William Auld, estas dulingva angla-Esperanta lernolibro.

Answer (score 0):

A great website to check out with interactive literature in the form of stories, music and other such media is lernu.net which requires you to create an account but it is a small price to pay (you don't actually have to pay) for such amazing resources.

Answer (score 0):

La ejo ‘Ekonomia Bulteno pri Usono’, rekte kaj libere atingebla, havas strikte paralelajn tekstojn angla – Esperanta. Jen la ligilo al ĝi:

https://ekonomiabultenopriusono.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is a book available on Amazon with 10 short items from English literature (such as 'Curfew Must Not Ring Tonight'), each with a parallel (i.e., side-by-side) Esperanto translation:

[https://www.amazon.com/literature-parallel-Esperanto-translation-students/dp/B0CQCGBTLQ/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2SF8ZS4WPX9MH&keywords=%22items+from+English%22&qid=1702805581&s=books&sprefix=items+from+english+%2Cstripbooks%2C185&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CQCGBTLQ)